# how to maintain state for so many views of particular application

Tags: iphone

I have 1  application.
It  has  almost 32 views in hiereachy   with back button.
I  want  tomaintain  state of  each and every view and  also if  i bcak the state of that view also maintains
is  there any way  to   do  it   by   code   or   by  the setting

I'm  asking   for  iphone

My simple   question  is  if  i put two text fields  in my  view   and  then  i press   home   button   and   then,i move   to another   application  and  then again i press   home   button    and   then  i   move  to  my   application ,i'm  able   to open   that   view which  i leave   and   also  my textfield or whatever i  fill will be maintained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application delegate's `-applicationWillTerminate:`, save the info by e.g.

```
....
NSUserDefaults* defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defs setObject:myFirstTextField.text forKey:@"firstTextField"];
[defs setObject:mySecondTextField.text forKey:@"firstTextField"];
...
```

And in `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` or `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, restore the info by

```
....
NSUserDefaults* defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
myFirstTextField.text = [defs stringForKey:@"firstTextField"];
mySecondTextField.text = [defs stringForKey:@"firstSecondField"];
...
```

In general, whatever you want to save and restore can be placed into `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: and  if  i leave from my 5 th view ,then  how   to   come  back   to   1st   view

Comment: if  i go to 5 th view after processing  1,2,3,4
then,how to come back   to   5  th view wen i'm coming  from  another  application to  my  application

Comment: You can store the identifier of the view as an integer by `-setInteger:forKey:`, and then restore it by `-integerForKey:` and do anything you want with this integer. It is very flexible. But I don't understand what you mean by "come back to 5th view". Is that kind of 5th descendant *a la* `UINavigationController` or 5th element in a form *a la* `UITextField`?

Comment: You have to push all 5 view controllers on the nav controller's stack. Make sure you have `animated:NO` when you do that.

Comment: I'm saying that i leave from 5 th view means that i go to 5 th view ,then press home button and then go to another application then again press home button and then back to my application at that time always 1 st view opens but as i leaved from 5 th view then 5 th view  must be opened
what should i do for that?

Comment: You still haven't answer whether it's `UINavigationController`-like (which they're called *view controllers* not views) or `UITextField`-like. If it's the former you need to save the whole path to that *view controller* too.

Comment: what  is  this forKey:@"firstTextField"] here?

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the NSCoding methods on all your views and view controllers, you can save all your stuff in a keyed archiver that can easily be restored at a later time.  You should implement

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
```

to save all your classes' instance variable data, and

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
```

to restore it later.  Look at the NSCoding documentation; there should be an official apple guide on how to implement and use this properly.

The nice thing about all this is that UIView and UIViewController and their subclasses all implement these as well, so for instance if you encode a UINavigationController you will automatically have all of the view controllers that exist on the navigation stack encoded for free as well, which should get you what you need if you implement the NSCoding methods in your own classes as well.